# is there any workaround to exceed the limits of search twitter api?

Tags: twitter

Anyone know how to circumvent the limits of search twitter?

I would like to get somewhere around 1 million tweets, is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I bet its going to be against the terms of use, even if it does exist

Comment: You likely have to use a 3rd party source to do this.  Take a look at this post and the comment I left here earlier this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046713/accessing-public-timelines-using-twitters-new-api

Answer (score 0):

Absent finding a third party data provider (e.g., paying for data) or skirting Twitter's terms of service, there is no way around this. I've worked with the Search API extensively, and you'll never pull in close to 1 million Tweets with it.

Using the search API, the best you're going to get is upwards of 2 weeks of recent tweets for a given query, or upwards of a few thousand Tweets.

It **is** possible to pull in a larger number of tweets by providing begin/end dates in your query -- for instance, you can try to pull in the maximum number of tweets for a given query for today, yesterday, two days ago, etc. I've been able to pull in upwards of 12,000 Tweets for a given query using this method -- but that's a far cry from 1 million.

Is there any reason you can't use the streaming API, which has fewer limitations than the search API.