# Accessing public timelines using Twitter's new API

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter

Owing to the fact that Twitter have recently [overhauled their API](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api), I'm trying to think of ways to get my Zend CMS application to access the public timelines of clients. I'm currently using this:

```
$twitterSearch = new Zend_Service_Twitter_Search('json');
$output = $twitterSearch->search("from:$username", array('rpp' => $total, 'page' => $page));
return $output['results'];
```

To return the required data - this works without a hitch. The problem, however, is that it only seems to be returning very recent tweets. Looking at their documentation for the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search), they specify a time limit of just **6-9 days** of data being available for use.

A lot of clients have timelines with old tweets (some from early 2012) which they want displayed. Is there any other way, apart from the Twitter Search API, that I can access third party timelines? I've looked into [Zend's other Twitter features](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.twitter.html) but they only seem concerned with accessing sensitive data that requires oAuth authentication (direct messages, friends, posting to your timeline, etc.). I just want to access the public timelines for a particular username. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, you'd think that with all of the data twitter collects, we'd be able to search and archive everything as we please, but I guess they're pretty hellbent on "streaming data" rather than old data.  Have you looked at this? http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/

Comment: But why are you running a search when you need tweets from a particular user? You can use the user_timeline feature instead. That'll show the last 'n' number of tweets from the user regardless of how old the tweets are. Because when you search, you get only 6-9 days of tweets, and if a user has not tweeted in about two weeks, you get nothing.

Comment: @ArjunAbhynav Their new API (v 1.1) only allows you to access `user_timeline` with oAuth. I wanted to avoid using oAuth if at all possible.

Comment: Oh yes, that is there. Well but now with the rate limits, it is nearly impossible to avoid using oAuth, unless you cache results. It was a really bad move by Twitter. I can already see that a million Twitter widgets in blogs and what not, have stopped working.